# Rotation of a vector around origin

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given a vector $V$,  Let $R_\theta(V)$ be the result of rotating V around the origin through an angle $\theta$.

Derive a general equation for $R_\theta(x,y)$

**My attempt using unit-circle:**

$cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r} \rightarrow  r cos(\theta) = x $

$sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r} \rightarrow  r sin(\theta) = y $

This implies:

$R_\theta(x,y)$ = $(r cos(\theta) ,  r sin(\theta)) $

**The book I am following however gives the following answer:**

$R_\theta(x,y)=(x cos (\theta) - y sin(\theta), x sin(\theta) + y cos(\theta))$

--

What's wrong with my derivation? it seems to work

Comment: You are mixing up two different things here. Your expression gives the polar coordinates for a point with cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ (without the application of any rotation). Their expression represents the cartesian coordinates that result from applying a rotation to the point $(x,y)$.

Comment: Don't really, follow your argument can you clarify please? The two expressions seem to be equivalent. Example:  $V=(2,0)$, $\theta=\pi/2$ Then using my expression  $R_{\pi/2}(2,0) = (2cos (\pi/2), 2sin(\pi/2)) = (0,2)$.   (Note: $r=2$) . Using the books expression:   $R_{\pi/2}(2,0) = (2cos(\pi/2)-0sin(\pi/2), 2sin(\pi/2) + 0cos(\pi/2)) = (0,2)$

Comment: Your relations rotate the vector $(1,0)$. (set $\theta=0$). You are asked to solve a more general case.

Comment: unless I am missing something, my relations can rotate any 2d vector. Note that $r$ is  calculated using Pythagoras,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation of angle $\theta$ will map $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(\cos(\theta+\frac\pi2),\sin(\theta+\frac\pi2))=$ $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.

Hence by linearity

$$(x,y)\to x\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)+y\,(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta).$$

Comment: Agreed, but my question is more one the lines of,   is the relation I derived using the unit circle equivalent to the one provided by the book? and If this so, then why is the one given by the book preferred?

Comment: @SFD: grrr, I already commented on this !

Comment: sorry didn't see your comment, would appreciate , if you could explain intuitively why my relation is not general.

Comment: @SFD: double grrr, I said it. Make $\theta=0$ !

Comment: $R_{\theta=0}(2,0) = (2 cos 0, 2 sin 0) =  (2,0) $  ?

Comment: @SFD: try other examples.

Comment: I see, thanks for you answer. It makes sense now,  Basically, my solution  will not work for any vectors that are not on the axis, cuz its not taking account of there  existing rotation with respect to the axis.

Comment: @SFD: and $r$ is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Take the point $(x,y)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$ in polar coordinates. Then assuming we rotate anticlockwise,
$$\begin{aligned}R_{\theta}(x,y)&=(r\cos(\phi+\theta),r\sin(\phi+\theta))\\
&=(r\cos\phi\cos\theta-r\sin\phi\sin\theta,r\sin\phi\cos\theta+r\cos\phi\sin\theta)\\
&=(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)\\
\end{aligned}$$